# mouseenter doesn't get fired first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i go to part where the mouseenter is it doesn't get fired first time. But if i leave it and return and to the same part, then the mouseenter gets fired. I been desperately looking for a solution. The code part looks like this

```
if(target.hasClass("level1")) {
                    console.log(target);
                        target.mouseenter(function () {
                            newThis.focus(event, target);
                            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                                newThis.focus(event, target);
                            }, 200);
                        }).mouseleave(function () {
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                        });
                }
```

So yeah, the code works, but it doesnt get fired the first time.

Comment: What is the context of the above code? What is `target` and how is it set?

Comment: I have an ul and li setup. I want to, when entering the li section, it triggers this 
newThis.focus(event, target); and puts a timeout, so i can navigate to the submenu without it changing the menu, because i hoved over some else li.

All of that works apart from i have to go though li's first time and return before this event
newThis.focus(event, target); is getting called.

otherwise it will skip " target.mouseenter" when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

That's intentional: it only fires on crossing the boundary upon entering.

Does the `mouseover` event solve your problem?

Comment: Haven't tried mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` handler within an `if`. So once the if statement is fullfilled you set mouse enter/leave handlers.
This means the events will only fire *after* the if was executed. So another mouse movement is required to trigger the newly added event.

You will typically create the handlers when loading the page and filtering inappropriate calls later.

Without knowing further context - try a concept where you don't need the if.
See example below.

```js
let timer;

$('.level1')
.mouseenter(function (event) {
    var newThis = $(this).find('input');
    newThis.focus();
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        newThis.focus();
    }, 200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <article>
    <section>
      <h1>Hello.</h1>
      <p>Article Text</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <form>
        <div class="level1">
          <input type="text" name="one" />
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <input type="text" name="two" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </article>
</body>
</html>
```